# Presence:true vs. null:false in migration table

Tags: validation, activerecord, null, migration

I'm working on a group project, and a team member suggested adding `presence:true` to the migration file instead of `null:false`.

for example:

```
create_table :item do |t|
  t.string :name, presence:true
```

vs.

```
create_table :item do |t|
  t.string :name, null:false
```

I've only seen null:false in a migration file, and was wondering if you can actually add presence:true to a migration instead of `null:false`, or if `presence:true` should only be a validation in the model. If so, which is best practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what database you use and which keywords it supports.
 So if a db that you use supports keyword *'presence:true'*, you can use it.

However the best practice is to use **null:false**, I've never seen anything other.

Plus, Rails has a special migration method for this case, and it's called *change_column_null* http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null

Hope it's useful for you.